# Async scrolling for ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I have an `ImageView` and a `ListView` below it.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now I want an "async scrolling" effect, i.e., when scrolling the `ListView` downwards after initialization, the height of `ImageView` will gradually decreases (with 2x of `ListView` scrolling speed) to 0. When the `ListView` is scrolled (upwards) to top but user is still scrolling upwards, the `ImageView` will correspondingly increases in original height (200dp, also 2x speed).

How can I implement it?